# Laravel Valet Linux: Can't connect MariaDB/Mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel, mariadb

I've been trying to connect to MariaDB in the last 24 hours after installing Laravel Linux Valet without success, I'm getting to the point of giving up.

```
brew services start mariadb
```

I get this

```
sh: 1: list: not found
Error: Failure while executing:  load -w 
/home/bruno/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
```

I've installed mysql-server, mysql-client, granted permissions to root user but still no success. If I

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

I enter mysql but can't connect through **root@localhost** or **root@127.0.0.1** on Workbench

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Valet install a MySql server, you maybe have a conflict with this instance of MySql. Try to shutdown valet with `valet stop` and start mariadb again. I suggest you to use the integrated MySql server of valet but if you insist to use mariadb, there is maybe a workaround to use mariadb with valet integrated.